# How to get the max text length for a fixed width/height EditText and text size

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have an `EditText` with fixed width and height.  I hope `EditText` could automatically reduce text size when there're too many length/texts.  In order to achieve this, my question is:

1. How can I get the max length by giving fixed width/height and text
   size?
2. What text size should I use by giving fixed with/height and text
   content?

Comment: So are you saying that you programatically want to make  edit text  behave more maturely and automatically reduce text size when there's too many arguments ?

Comment: Why don't you set the max length ? Setting max-length is quite easy : `android:maxLength="10"`

Comment: @TheDarkKnight, maxLength is not flexible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so, i have gleaned some ideas about it and i am presenting it to you. I have not yet tested it. So first what we need to do here is get edit text max-length. But, only limited parameters have their getters, so I don't think you can read it .

So write length (Say 12) in values folder and use it in xml layout and your java class. Now its not hard-coded .

**1)Create integer.xml in values**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <item type="integer" name="max_length">12</item>
</resources>
```

**2)In layout**

```
<TextView  android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLength="@integer/max_length"
    />
```

**3) in Java :**

```
int maxLength = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.max_length);
```

Now we have to adjust the font size of the text, so we need to get that first :

```
    msgInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgInput);
    msgInput.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
    {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    if ((msgInput.getMaxHeight() > maxLength) || (msgInput.getTextSize() > maxLength))
    {
    msgInput.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
    else
    {
    int height = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    msgInput.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, height));
    }
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
    int after) {         
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
    int count) {         
    }

    });
```

All in all you have to apply [TextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#addTextChangedListener%28android.text.TextWatcher%29) here .